# Azure Data Factory Error: SqlColumnNameMismatchByCaseSensitive. Is it possible to Ignore Case Sensitivity with SnowFlake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm not sure what group this question should be targetted at.

I have created a copy activity from SnowFlake to Azure SQLDB. The connection is working fine. However, the copy activity is giving me an error suggesting there is Column Name mismatch in terms of case sensivity.

```
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlColumnNameMismatchByCaseSensitive,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'CONTENTTYPEID' in DataSet '[OBLIXXXXXX]' cannot be found in physical Sql database. Column matching is case sensitive. Column 'ContentTypeID' appears similar. Check the DataSet(s) configuration to proceed further.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.,Source=System.Data,'
```

[image]

For example, the columns in SnowFlake are capitails by default, see below image
[image]

However, when copying over to Azure SQLDB the copy activity doesn't like the fact I'm copying from  a table where the columns are all capitals while the columns in SQLDB are both lower case.

[image]

So, is there a way of getting the copy activity to ignore case sensitivity?

Updating the question with the mapping screenshot

[image]

The sink is parameterized, so can't hardcode mappings
[image]

Comment: Are you using automapping in copy activity?

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thanks for reaching out. No, I'm not using automapping in the copy activity

Comment: Could you share the mapping setting screenshot also?

Comment: Hi @Aswin, I have updated the question with the mapping screenshot as requested. Thanks

Comment: Can you `Import schemas` and map the columns manually between source and sink

Comment: @Aswin, not would not be a feasible option, because there are 100's of tables with different columns that need to copied to Azure SQLDB. At the moment the sink is parameterized to accommodate any table. See updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256036/discussion-between-aswin-and-patterson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per this [MS Documnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#default-mapping) ADF auto mapping is a case sensitive**

To work around this,

1. you need to match the case of column either with snowflake or SQL database.

To convert the columns names In SQL table You can use following query: It will change the all-column names of all tables to capital format.

```sql
DECLARE @sqlstring nvarchar(512) -- sql to execute
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(512)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select 'exec sp_rename '''+QUOTENAME(b.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(a.name)+''','''+UPPER(a.name)+''',''column''' as cmd
from syscolumns a, sysobjects b 
where a.id=b.id and b.type='U' 
order by b.name

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @cmd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      set @sqlstring = @cmd;

      EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlstring;

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @cmd
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And now you can use this tables to get the data from snowflake.

2. Using data flow activity, you can transform the data as below:

- Take Dataflow activity with two Sources as below one is snowflake from which you need to transform and the SQL table of which you want the column name as header
  First source (SQL table (destination table) to get the column names):
  [image]
  Second source (Snowflake table to get the data)
  [image]
- Then after first source take filter transformation to filter as we only want column name not data as its destination table with `False()` condition.
  [image]
  Data preview:
  [image]
- After this take Union trandformation to get the data of snowflake table.![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/Qlge1bC.png)Data preview:
  [image]
- Now you can transform this data.

Comment: Hi @Pratik, this is fantastic. Thank you very much